Drools lock-on-active does not fire rule
I have this just small example and I expected to have execution of two rules, but only one (RULE 1) fired. what's wrong on this?
drools version 7.74.1
java 8
rule "RULE 1"
    agenda-group "some-group"
    when
    then
        insert( new Object( ) );
        System.out.println("RULE 1 RUN");
end


rule "RULE 2"
    agenda-group "some-group"
    lock-on-active
    salience -1
    when
        Object( )
    then
        System.out.println("RULE 2 RUN");
end

Tried to debug who activate Rule 2 and saw in stacktrace that Rule 1 on haltRuleFiring evaluates LHS from Rule 2

It's working correctly. lock-on-active prevents rules from activating if the agenda group is already active. Both "RULE 1" and "RULE 2" are in the same agenda-group, "some-group". Since you're seeing "RULE 1" fire, the agenda-group is active; since it's active, "RULE 2" does not fire.
It's not entirely clear why you're using lock-on-active, or salience,  in these rules, so it's not possible to suggest how to fix it. But if you want RULE 2 to fire because RULE 1 has modified working memory, just remove lock-on-active. (And remove salience too, you don't need it and it's generally not good practice.) If you want RULE 1 to not re-fire if the agenda-group is re-triggered, add not( Object() ) to the condition/when clause of RULE 1.
More information about lock-on-active is in this blog post. It's quite old (2012), but still relevant and has examples.

I know that salience is a bad practice, but I have a huge set of rules which changes and depends from same fields. I expected to have some ranges of saliences in which I will do some work, but this behavior with lock-on-active is strange for me. I just want to execute RULE 2 once after RULE 1 and lock-on-active should achieve these, but not...

You might need no-loop instead. Or otherwise design your rules better so that if you do activate the same group multiple times or refire/reevaluate the rules, that they won't execute a second time. But lock-on-active basically means that you can fire one rule in the group, which doesn't sound like what you want. The blog post I linked is very good at explaining.

no-loop prevent only self-looping, when rule modifying property in object from which depends. In my case I just want to achieve to execute rule once, and it works only when I add Object to memory before firing rules. Why when I inserting object in runtime the lock-on-active rules never fired?
